# Selected/Restricted Autosubmit with Better Exposed Filters in Drupal

Tags: search, views

I'm using the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module to manipulate the filters in my view. It works great except for one issue that's affecting the whole layout.

Within my view I have four exposed filters out one is a Search (*Search Terms*). The auto submit works perfectly with the checkboxes filter but makes the search unusable. It basically submits it on every keypress and that hinders writing the complete word.

Is it possible, that I could have autosubmit on all filters except one (*Search Terms* filter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-submit feature is a part of the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. It relies on the auto-submit [CTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) behavior. This plugin disables auto-submit for form elements that have the CSS class `ctools-auto-submit-exclude`. You can embed this JavaScript within the form header to disable auto submission on text fields.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('div.views-exposed-form input[type="text"]').addClass('ctools-auto-submit-exclude');
});
```

You can adjust your jQuery selector accordingly for other form elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shawn, I added this JQuery which changed the `input` to this:- `<input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="china" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text ctools-auto-submit-processed ctools-auto-submit-exclude" placeholder="Keyword">`. Unfortunately, it still didn't work and is still submitting the form.

Comment: The JS triggering this is under the CTools module as **js/auto-submit.js**. You can set breakpoints on the code to see why/why not it's triggering submission on text field change.

Comment: The JS, for some reason didn't work. I had to create a module. See below.

Comment: Thanks. The solution above probably depends on when the JS is triggered. Your solution is probably the better option since it adds the class before any JS is fired.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That was precisely the case.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation in CTools suggests adding the class `ctools-auto-submit-exclude` in the element `#attributes` key for the form element you don't want to processed:

```
function MODULE_search_submission_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
  if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form") {
    if (isset($form['keys'])) {
      $form['keys']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'ctools-auto-submit-exclude';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will exclude the autocomplete in Drupal 8.

```
$form['keys']['#attributes'] = ['data-bef-auto-submit-exclude' => ''];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 better exposed use data attribute to exclude an item :

```
$form['keys']['#attributes']['data-bef-auto-submit-exclude'] = '';
```